# Отправка формы с сайта на whatsapp с business api

Tags: php, form, whatsapp

Ребят, всем привет. Подскажите как настроить отправку форму обратной связи в whatsapp? Имея business api. Поделитесь готовыми плагинами, скриптами или статьями, в интернете нечего толкового по своим запросам не нашёл. Подскажите пожалуйста, буду благодарен!

Comment: вот детальнейшее описание о том, как работать с business api в whats app:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp
Что вам ещё нужно? Никто не опишет лучше самих разработчиков

Comment: @Inventor Это я тоже видел, интересует как сделать отправку с полей формы. Допустим имя, телефон и все такое.

Comment: для начала узнайте вообще что такое api сайта, как оно работает и что позволяет делать